# How to get list of user roles after upgrading from .NET framework to .NET Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, upgrade, .net-framework-version

Previously in .NET framework 4.6, my code to get role of specific user looked like this:

```
using System.Web.Security;

//......

var userRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);

// To get all roles:
var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
```

But after upgrading my web application project to .NET 6, I am in the process to fix dependencies and code in class libraries and I haven't found alternative for `System.Web.Security.Roles` so far.

I searched on Google but all I found was about Identity Roles using .NET Core but that will require db changes too so not looking forward to identity thing.

Please let me know about possible solutions.

Comment: Were you using `FormsAuthentication` previously? Show us your code where you set User Roles/Claims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject the `RoleManager` and get roles like below in ASP.NET Core:

```
public class TestController
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public TestController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public void GetAllRoles()
    {
        var roles = _roleManager.Roles?.ToList();
    }
}
```

Be sure register the RoleManager in Program.cs(beyond .NET 5.0) or Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```